# Ввод IP адреса в текстовое поле

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Нужна ваша помощь. Нужно правильно и корректно вводить IP адрес в поле LineEdit
Я знаю о масках ввода и регулярных выражениях, но если их использовать, то получается вот такая штука:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота, то некрасиво и неравномерно вводиться строка, а хотелось что-то типа такого вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно такое сделать, чтобы ввод адреса был нормальным? Буду очень сильно благодарен :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идём в дизайнер и создаём пустой `QWidget`. Клацаем по нему правой кнопкой и нажимаем `Изменить styleSheet...`. В появившемся диалоге вписываем стиль для серого обрамления всего виджета:

```
border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
```

Далее накидываем 4 `QLineEdit`'а в строку. Не забываем выставить в свойствах выравнивание текста по середине. Каждому также прописываем стиль:

```
border: none;
```

Между ними создаём по `QLabel`'у, итого 3 штуки, вбиваем в качестве текста точку. Стиль прописываем:

```
background: white;
border: none;
```

Каждому виджету в свойство `maximumSize` указываем высоту `30`.

Компонуем по горизонтали все созданные виджеты. Свойству `layoutSpacing` ставим `0`, свойства `layout*Margin` ставим так, чтобы рамка не уезжала (у меня `2`).

Для проверки того, входит ли в диапазон `[0, 255)`, в конструктор добавить что-то подобное:

```
const auto* validator = new QIntValidator(0, 255, this);
octet_1->setValidator(validator);
octet_2->setValidator(validator);
octet_3->setValidator(validator);
octet_4->setValidator(validator);

auto lockOctet = [validator](QLineEdit* octet) {
    return [octet,validator](const QString& str) {
        int pos = 0;
        if(validator->validate(const_cast<QString&>(str), pos) != QValidator::Acceptable) {
            octet->setText(str.chopped(1));
        }
    };
};

connect(octet_1, &QLineEdit::textEdited, lockOctet(octet_1));
connect(octet_2, &QLineEdit::textEdited, lockOctet(octet_2));
connect(octet_3, &QLineEdit::textEdited, lockOctet(octet_3));
connect(octet_4, &QLineEdit::textEdited, lockOctet(octet_4));
```

У меня выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и конечно всё это лучше обернуть в отдельный класс.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, но большое спасибо :)

Comment: @razorqhex что именно?